# How can I make the user choose between two options (Available or not Available) in IOS?

Tags: ios, input-fields

If i want the user to choose one of the two options(available or not available)  ... what is the best thing for this design in ios application..I tried to use fragments buttons, is that true?

How can I make the user choose between two options which are available or not available for each item in the list

Answer (score 1):

When there are only two choices, and the choices are just positive/negative (yes/no, available/not available...), the best choice is often to use a checkbox or the equivalent (in the case of iOS, a [switch](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/switches/)).

However, other than the verbosity of it (and the possible issues with the space it takes in some localisations), alternate choices like a [segmented control](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/) may be appropriate.